# Pandas Ffill on rows that contain only NaN

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, imputation

I want to combine sklearn’s imputation and Panda’s Ffill to fill in missing data.
This is what my dataFrame, `df` looks like

```
FeatA  FeatB  FeatC  FeatD
  B      A      B      D
 NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
  A      A      B       C
 NaN     A      A       A
 NaN     B      A       A
```

I want to use Ffill to fill rows which contain only `NaN` (e.g row 2), with the previous value.

If rows contain only a few `NaN`, e.g if there is at least 1 value, use imputation to fill NaN with the most frequent value in the row.

I’m using a LabelEncoder to convert the String values to integers – it’s alphabetical. `A=0, B=1, C=2, D = 3`.
 In order to make sure that NaN get the value 4 , I convert NaN to “Z” – using `data = df.fillna("Z")`

I then impute the data so that any value with `Z` is filled with the most frequent value in the row – 
`imp = Imputer(missing_values=4, strategy= 'most_frequent', axis=1)`

So, I want to fill rows which have only `NaN` using `ffill`.

Then I’m using the LabelEncoder and imputation to fill other `NaN` with the most frequent value in the row.

If I can select rows that contain only `NaN` and apply the `ffill` function to only those rows, then I can use imputation on the other Nan. How can I do this?

Comment: `df.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)`. This will propagate the last valid observation forward and change the `Nan` values accordingly.

Comment: "So, I want to fill rows which have only NaN using ffill." This would make the row same as the above row. Why don't you just remove that row?

Comment: This is for input to a classification model - I do not want to delete empty rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first duplicate the `Nan` only rows with it's previous value and continue as shown:

```
## Select rows containing all Nan values and replace them with the preceding values
In [2]: df.loc[df.isnull().all(axis=1), :] = df.ffill()    

In [3]: df.fillna('Z', inplace=True)
```

Initialize `LabelEncoder` and perform `fit`:

```
In [4]: enc = LabelEncoder()

In [5]: enc.fit(np.unique(df.values))
Out[5]: LabelEncoder()

In [6]: df = df.apply(enc.transform)
```

Impute missing values with the most frequent elements along the columns:

```
In [7]: imp = Imputer(missing_values=4, strategy='most_frequent', axis=1)

In [8]: imp.fit_transform(df)
Out[8]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  1.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  1.,  3.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  2.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.]])
```